# CKEditor: Restore caret position after calling editor#setData

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I have a CKEditor instance where I want to manipulate the content, and restore the caret position to where it was afterwards. The problem is that, when you call `setData`, it resets the caret to the beginning of the editor. This is understandable if you are changing all of the content, but I am only making minor changes to the data.

```
editor.on('change', function () {
  var data = editor.getData();
  // manipulate `data`
  var manipulatedData = data;
  editor.setData(manipulatedData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for you query. instead of adding setdata. you can use inserthtml

```
editor.insertHtml(manipulatedData).
```

Will keep the cursor at the end position after inserting the data

Comment: Thanks this simple solution works great, I had trouble setting the caret position at the end after doing setData, don't forget setData is asynchronous so when you want to clear CKEditor or "trim" to a character limit it's best to do a callback... to the setData function

Comment: It's duplicating content? how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is setData to '', then use insertHtml with your content.
setData is asyncronius, so you must use a callback function. This is the code that works:

```
oEditor.setData('', {callback: function() {
oEditor.insertHtml(YOUR_HTML);
}
});
```

Comment: Try for your effort to help, but it just make the caret go to the end of the line.

Comment: Ah! setData is asyncron! That's the solution!  I had tried in vain to insert content via insertHtml after deleting via setData and the editor was always empty.